# Save data from clientside withouth a backend

Tags: database, angular, client-side

I have a very simple webpage created in angular, with no backed. Now I would like to store some very simple user statistics data in some way, without involving a backend. File, database or some other thing that I can access from clientside.

I had a look at MongoDB which looks very cool, I can access that via a REST api which is perfect. Only problem here is that the api is hosted on https, which my domain are not. That means I cannot connect to the api because of CORS error. And I would like to avoid buying an SSL certificate.

So do I have any options here? Storing data from clientside without a backend and SSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually to go with Mongodb, and add a free SSL certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/